# How to solve this calculation for Linux

Tags: linux, sh

I am having some problem. I have the master value= 5 and slave value= 10. 
If Slave value are bigger than Master value then echo "NEW RXID FILES ARE TRUE"
But problem is i am getting echo "NEX RXID FILES ARE FALSE !!!!!!" 
How come it will be like that? Suppostly slave value really is bigger than master value but in the script it told me is was NOT. 
Below is my code. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh
MasterID=0
SlaveID=0
MasterID=`sort -n ${1} | awk '{print $1}'|tail -1`
SlaveID=`sort -n ${2} | awk '{print $1}'|head -1`

echo "Last ID of Masterkey =" $MasterID #133
echo "First ID of NewRXID =" $SlaveID   #105

ControlID=`sort ${1} ${2}| awk 'seen[$1]++ == 1'|wc -l`
echo "Check MasterID to SlaveID =" $ControlID

if [[ ${MasterID} < ${SlaveID} ]] ; then
#if [[ $ControlID < 1 ]]; then
#if [[ '$MasterID' > '$SlaveID' ]] && [[ $controlID < 1 ]]; then
echo "NEW RXID FILES ARE TRUE"
else
echo "NEX RXID FILES ARE FALSE !!!!!!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`<` is an ascii comparison. Try `-lt` instead for int comparisons.

Replace

```
if [[ ${MasterID} < ${SlaveID} ]] ; then
```

with

```
if [ ${MasterID} -lt ${SlaveID} ] ; then
```

Source:  [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

Comment: `[ ... ]` is only necessary if the OP is not using `bash`; otherwise, `[[ $MasterID -lt $SlaveID ]]` works just fine, although `(( MasterId < SlaveId ))` would be clearer.